# SQL / VBScript / Intelligent Algorithm to find sum combinations quickly

Tags: algorithm, ms-access, vba

Am trying to list out all the possible sequential (continuous and forward direction only) sum combinations , within the same subject.
Listing out the row_id and the number of rows involved in the sum.

```
Sample :

Input (Source Table :) 

DLID    Subject Total   
1   Science 70  
2   Science 70  
3   Science 70  
4   Science 70  
5   Maths   80  
6   Maths   80  
7   English 90  
8   English 90  
9   English 90  
10  Science 75  

Expected Result :           
ID  Number of Rows  Subject Total
1   1   Science 70
2   1   Science 70
3   1   Science 70
4   1   Science 70
5   1   Maths   80
6   1   Maths   80
7   1   English 90
8   1   English 90
9   1   English 90
10  1   Science 75
1   2   Science 140
2   2   Science 140
3   2   Science 140
5   2   Maths   160
7   2   English 180
8   2   English 180
1   3   Science 210
2   3   Science 210
7   3   English 270
1   4   Science 280
```

VBSript Code :

' myarray - reads the entire table from access database
' "i" is the total number of rows read
' "j" if to access each row one by one
' "m" is the number of subsequent rows with same subject , we are trying to check
' "n" is a counter to start from each row and check upto m - 1 rows whether same sub
' "k" is used to store the results into "resultarray"

```
myarray(0,j) = holds the row_id
myarray(1,j) = holds the subject
myarray(2,j) = holds the score
myarray(3 4 5 6 are other details
i is the total number of rows - around 80,000
There can be conitnuous records from the same subject as many as 700 - 800
m = is the number of rows matching / number of rows leading to the sum



For m = 1 to 700
For j = 0 to i-m
matchcount = 1

For n = 1 to m-1 
if  myarray(1,j) = myarray (1,j+n) Then 
matchcount = matchcount + 1
Else
Exit For
End If
Next

If matchcount = m Then
resultarray(2,k) = 0
For o = 0 to m - 1
resultarray(2,k) = CDbl(resultarray(2,k)) + CDbl (myarray (2,j+o))
resultarray(1,k) = m
resultarray(0,k) = ( myarray (0,j) )
resultarray(3,k) = ( myarray (3,j) )
resultarray(4,k) = ( myarray (4,j) )
resultarray(5,k) = ( myarray (1,j) )
resultarray(7,k) = ( myarray (5,j) )
resultarray(8,k) = ( myarray (6,j) )
Next
resultarray(2,k) = round(resultarray(2,k),0)
k = k + 1
ReDim Preserve resultarray(8,k)
End If

Next
Next
```

Code is working perfect , but is very slow.
Am dealing with 80,000 row and from 5 to 900 continuous rows of same subject.
So the number of combinations , comes in a few millions.
Takes few hours for one set of 80,000 rows. have to do many sets daily.

Please suggest how to speed this up.
Better Algorithm / Code Improvements / Different Language to code
Please assist.

Comment: Can you please update this question so that we can help?  a) include your SQL that populates your arrays.  b) strip irrelevant code (eg your "other" arrays). c) use meaningful variable names and code comments so we don't need to guess what it's doing, eg What are all these "magic" constants? is it 900 rows, 800 rows, or 700 continuous rows?

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain what you code does. Walk us through the process to explain your sample output. Also, please explain the `ms-access` tag: I see nothing in the code that looks Access-specific.

Comment: Also, if this is homework, that's OK - but you should make this clear, and IMHO you should really only accept an answer that properly explains the concepts to you (as opposed to just giving you the solution).

Comment: @Sepster SQL code is just a simple select statement that fetches all the rows from a table into myarray. There is nothing which is irrelevant. I have tried to tell you what the variables are what "myarray" is , what "i" is, what "m" is. Other variables are declared and used within the code itself , on purpose of counting and matching etc. The variable are not used before this code neither after.
magic constants - the number of continuous rows with the same subject can be as high as 900. Total number of rows in the database is 80,000+.Indicating this to show how number of combination can b high

Comment: @GordThompson I read all the rows (around 80,000) from an access database into "myarray". Then try to generate all the possible "sum" of the Totals within the same score. Only for rows which are from the same subject and appear one after the other. I keep a record of the sum , number of rows added to get the sum , and which subject into "resultarray". 
Mentioned access , because am using an access database from where I fetch the records. My code meets the purpose , but looking at ways to improve the speed.

Comment: @arcotenterprises You've said "There is nothing which is irrelevant", yet your code contains this "myarray(3 4 5 6 are _other details_" along with several lines pertaining to these arrays.  If 900 is your max, then why does the (I presume associated) loop go to 700?  Single letter variable names are not acceptable in any high-level language code but computer science exam questions, where they are used to _intentionally_ hide their meaning and/or confuse you - which is exactly what they're doing here (for me at least).  If you want my help, don't argue with me, rather, accept my advice.

Comment: @Sepster , This is part of a bigger work I am trying to complete. My code is working , this is not homework. I am looking for suggestions whether improvements can be done and of course , once we get the answers we will have new ideas as well. Obviously for me to implement it into my overall code , I will need to understand the concept. 

Please go through the code spending a few minutes , you will be able to understand what is happening. It looks irrelevant to the first time viewer , but once you understand what is happening , you will appreciate it.

Comment: @arcotenterprises "It looks irrelevant to the first time viewer" We agree on something.  "but once you understand what is happening, you will appreciate it."  What _is_ happening is that I'm moving on to a question that I can understand and possibly help with :-)  Good luck with it (sincerely).

Comment: @Sepster , Accepted. my array(3 ,4 , 5, 6 are other columns which will be required to be copied - holding more information. Purpose of mentioning is that there are columns than showcased in the example.

The numbers 700 is because one particular set had that many continuous rows. This can be higher or lower. Idea of mentioning is only to get an indication of the number of combinations possible. Not to be exactly put.

Comment: variables :
myarray - 2D array which fetches all the rows from the Access database
m = the number of highest continuous rows , we will try from 1 to 700
j = used to access each row one by one
n = used to check whether subsequent rows are the same Subject , upto 'm'
matchcount = to see if we get the number of subsequent rows with same subject equal to m
k = to populate the results into the "resultarray" , counter row wise

Comment: have tried to be as informative as possible. Please look at the example , that should provide an idea of what we are trying to acheive.

Comment: Your additional descriptions help. You may get better assistance if you click the "edit" link immediately below your question and put that information *in your code* (as VBA comments).

Comment: @arcotenterprises And change instances of eg `m` in your code to be `continuousRowLimit`, and `j` to `mainRowIterator`, and `n` to `previousRowsIterator`, etc etc.  If you've had no more help in another few hours (when I check back in) I'll see what I can do - but only if you promise to clean your code and question up so I don't need to think too hard about what it is I'm helping with ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the building blocks for a "real" Access (SQL) solution.

**Observation #1**

It seems to me that a good first step would be to add two Numeric (Long Integer) columns to the [SourceTable]:

[SubjectBlock] will number the "blocks" of rows where the subject is the same

[SubjectBlockSeq] will sequentially number the rows within each block

They both should be indexed (Duplicates OK). The code to populate these columns would be...

```
Public Sub UpdateBlocksAndSeqs()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim BlockNo As Long, SeqNo As Long, PrevSubject As String

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [SourceTable] ORDER BY [DLID]", dbOpenDynaset)

PrevSubject = "(an impossible value)"
BlockNo = 0
SeqNo = 0
DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans  ''speeds up bulk updates
Do While Not rst.EOF
    If rst!Subject <> PrevSubject Then
        BlockNo = BlockNo + 1
        SeqNo = 0
    End If
    SeqNo = SeqNo + 1
    rst.Edit
    rst!SubjectBlock = BlockNo
    rst!SubjectBlockSeq = SeqNo
    rst.Update
    PrevSubject = rst!Subject
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
DBEngine.Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

...and the updated SourceTable would be...

```
DLID    Subject   Total   SubjectBlock    SubjectBlockSeq
1       Science   70      1               1
2       Science   60      1               2
3       Science   75      1               3
4       Science   70      1               4
5       Maths     80      2               1
6       Maths     90      2               2
7       English   90      3               1
8       English   80      3               2
9       English   70      3               3
10      Science   75      4               1
```

(Note that I tweaked your test data to make it easier to verify the results below.)

Now as we iterate through the ever-increasing "length of sequence to be included in the total" we can quickly identify the "blocks" that are of interest simply by using a query like...

```
SELECT SubjectBlock FROM SourceTable WHERE SubjectBlockSeq=3
```

...which will return...

```
1
3
```

...indicating that when calculating the totals for a "run of 3" we won't need to look at blocks 2 ("Maths") and 4 (the last "Science" one) at all.

**Observation #2**

The first time through, when NumRows=1, is a special case: it just copies the rows from [SourceTable] into the [Expected Results] table. We can save time by doing that with a single query:

```
INSERT INTO ExpectedResult ( DLID, NumRows, Subject, Total, SubjectBlock, NextSubjectBlockSeq )
SELECT SourceTable.DLID, 1 AS Expr1, SourceTable.Subject, SourceTable.Total, 
    SourceTable.SubjectBlock, SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq+1 AS Expr2
FROM SourceTable;
```

You may notice that I have added two columns to the [ExpectedResult] table: [SubjectBlock] (as before) and [NextSubjetBlockSeq] (which is just [SubjectBlockSeq]+1). Again, they should both be indexed, allowing duplicates. We'll use them below.

**Observation #3**

As we continue looking for longer and longer "runs" to sum, each run is really just an earlier (shorter) run with an additional row tacked onto the end. If we write our results to the [ExpectedResults] table as we go along, we can re-use those values and not bother going back and adding up the individual values for the entire run.

When NumRows=2, the "add-on" rows are the ones where `SubjectBlockSeq>=2`...

```
SELECT SourceTable.*
FROM SourceTable
WHERE (((SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq)>=2))
ORDER BY SourceTable.DLID;
```

...that is...

```
DLID    Subject   Total SubjectBlock    SubjectBlockSeq
2       Science   60    1               2
3       Science   75    1               3
4       Science   70    1               4
6       Maths     90    2               2
8       English   80    3               2
9       English   70    3               3
```

...and the [ExpectedResult] rows with the "earlier (shorter) run" onto which we will be "tacking" the additional row are the ones

- from the same [SubjectBlock],
- with [NumRows]=1, and
- with `[ExpectedResult].[NextSubjectBlockSeq] = [SourceTable].[SubjectBlockSeq]`

so we can get the new totals and append them to [ExpectedResult] like this

```
INSERT INTO ExpectedResult ( DLID, NumRows, Subject, Total, SubjectBlock, NextSubjectBlockSeq )
SELECT SourceTable.DLID, 2 AS Expr1, SourceTable.Subject, 
    [ExpectedResult].[Total]+[SourceTable].[Total] AS NewTotal, 
    SourceTable.SubjectBlock, [SourceTable].[SubjectBlockSeq]+1 AS Expr2
FROM SourceTable INNER JOIN ExpectedResult 
    ON (SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq = ExpectedResult.NextSubjectBlockSeq) 
        AND (SourceTable.SubjectBlock = ExpectedResult.SubjectBlock)
WHERE (((SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq)>=2) AND (ExpectedResult.NumRows=1));
```

The rows appended to [ExpectedResult] are

```
DLID    NumRows Subject   Total SubjectBlock    NextSubjectBlockSeq
2       2       Science   130   1               3
3       2       Science   135   1               4
4       2       Science   145   1               5
6       2       Maths     170   2               3
8       2       English   170   3               3
9       2       English   150   3               4
```

**Now we're cookin'...**

Using the same logic as before, we can now process for NumRows=3. The only differences are that we will be inserting the value 3 into NumRows, and our selection criteria will be

```
WHERE (((SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq)>=3) AND (ExpectedResult.NumRows=2))
```

The complete query is

```
INSERT INTO ExpectedResult ( DLID, NumRows, Subject, Total, SubjectBlock, NextSubjectBlockSeq )
SELECT SourceTable.DLID, 3 AS Expr1, SourceTable.Subject, 
    [ExpectedResult].[Total]+[SourceTable].[Total] AS NewTotal, 
    SourceTable.SubjectBlock, [SourceTable].[SubjectBlockSeq]+1 AS Expr2
FROM SourceTable INNER JOIN ExpectedResult 
    ON (SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq = ExpectedResult.NextSubjectBlockSeq) 
        AND (SourceTable.SubjectBlock = ExpectedResult.SubjectBlock)
WHERE (((SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq)>=3) AND (ExpectedResult.NumRows=2));
```

and the rows appended to [ExpectedResult] are

```
DLID    NumRows Subject   Total SubjectBlock    NextSubjectBlockSeq
3       3       Science   205   1               4
4       3       Science   205   1               5
9       3       English   240   3               4
```

**Parameterization**

Since each successive query is so similar, it would be awfully nice if we could just write it once and use it repeatedly. Fortunately, we can, if we turn it into a "Parameter Query":

```
PARAMETERS TargetNumRows Long;
INSERT INTO ExpectedResult ( DLID, NumRows, Subject, Total, SubjectBlock, NextSubjectBlockSeq )
SELECT SourceTable.DLID, [TargetNumRows] AS Expr1, SourceTable.Subject, 
    [ExpectedResult].[Total]+[SourceTable].[Total] AS NewTotal, 
    SourceTable.SubjectBlock, [SourceTable].[SubjectBlockSeq]+1 AS Expr2
FROM SourceTable INNER JOIN ExpectedResult 
    ON (SourceTable.SubjectBlock = ExpectedResult.SubjectBlock) 
        AND (SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq = ExpectedResult.NextSubjectBlockSeq)
WHERE (((SourceTable.SubjectBlockSeq)>=[TargetNumRows]) 
    AND ((ExpectedResult.NumRows)=[TargetNumRows]-1));
```

Create a new Access query, paste the above into the SQL pane, and then save it as `pq_appendToExpectedResult`. (The "pq_" is just a visual cue that it's a Parameter Query.)

**Invoking a Parameter Query from VBA**

You can invoke (execute) a Parameter Query in VBA via a QueryDef object:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("pq_appendToExpectedResult")
qdf!TargetNumRows = 4  '' parameter value
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
```

**When to stop**

Now you can see that it's simply a matter of incrementing `NumRows` and re-running the Parameter Query, but when to stop? That's easy:

After incrementing your NumRows variable in VBA, test

```
DCount("DLID", "SourceTable", "SubjectBlockSeq=" & NumRows)
```

If it comes back 0 then you're done.

**Show me (all) the code**

Sorry, not right away. ;) Play around with this and let us know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
Please do try to complete this , I hope this question gets some viewers as this is not very simple. I have been able to get the desired result from my script , trying to make it faster now.

Comment: +1 Good looking algorithm. Still iterative in nature but looks like you've really thought about reducing unnecessary re-calculations etc.  Nice one.  You clearly know your way around MSACCESS.  I'd be interested in your thoughts re my MSSQL implementation and if it'd be easily converted.

Comment: wow , thanks. I am trying it now. I can fully understand the logic here. But Programming point of view ,  I was doing something really  silly. Was using .vbs files - which had the code I mentioned to do my tasks. Now to use your code trying to understand VBA and access. Give me some time. Please guide - as I am not very familiar with the VBA - MS Access Editor environment , hence having difficulty in playing with this.

Comment: @Gord Thompson , Would like to talk to you. Can you please email on arcotenterprises [at] gmail com. I am very impressed by how much improvement is there , and realizing how wrong my basics were. would like to discuss with you so that you can consider the entire project which I am trying to do. Must be simple few hours work for you. It can be paid as per your advise. Work is not a lot , builds up on what we have done here.

Comment: Just Perfect. Thanks a lot. Really.
After Inserting Firsttime.
Public Sub InsertintoExpectedResult()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
TargetNumRows = 2
Numberofblocks = DCount("DLID", "SourceTable", "SubjectBlockSeq=" & TargetNumRows)
Do While Numberofblocks > 0
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("pq_appendToExpectedResult")
qdf!TargetNumRows = TargetNumRows  '' parameter value
qdf.Execute
Numberofblocks = DCount("DLID", "SourceTable", "SubjectBlockSeq=" & TargetNumRows)
TargetNumRows = TargetNumRows + 1
Loop
Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Hi Gord, is there any reason that you can't build a number table and join to that to create a complete record set on one execution within the DBMS (as per my solution), instead of incrementing `NumRows` and calling/executing the procedure <900 times?  I would imagine this should improve the performance even further for @arcotenterprises.

Comment: @Gord Thompson , The table ExpectedResult - leads to crossing the 2 GB limit on the Access file. Also I need to match the values of the Total with another table. This process also takes a lot of time. Will I have to use MS SQL Server ? I also more carefully crafted VBA codes which do the work perfect , except for this bottleneck. Is connecting to SQL server and linking a table ExpectedResult possible and continuing with this same VBA good enough to remove the size constraint and improve search speed. Please assist. You have been very helpful throughout.

Comment: @Gord Thompson , The VBA code and query you have provided work flawlessly when the Input source Table (as in example) have lesser records. In my case the number of records is around 100,000. As a result the number of records generated for "ExpectedResult" reaches Ten million plus. This is taking very very long even on a fast computer. And also crossing the 2 GB limit. then searching this table also takes a long time. Have used your guidance for most parts of the access file , everything is fine just this last bottleneck. Please do advise.

Comment: @arcotenterprises If you are hitting the 2GB "wall" then you definitely need to migrate your data to another database environment. In SQL Server 2012 Express (and 2008 R2 Express) the database size is capped at 10GB so your data might "fit", but the Express editions are also limited to 1GB RAM per instance and one processor (max. 4 cores) so performance *might* still be an issue. Still, Express Edition is free, so it could well be worth a try. There is also a 180-day evaluation of SQL Server Enterprise that could give you an opportunity to do some performance comparisons.

Comment: @GordThompson , Yes Trying out SQL Express Server now. The things is everyhting is working perfect with all the VBA codes you provided. Will I have to scrap them all if using SQL Server , I was hoping that some minor tweaking with the access may be enough , because almost everything is complete. If you can PLEASE share your email and have a glance at the access file.

Comment: @arcotenterprises If you're able to strip your data source of all columns not relevant to Gord's particular algorithm, you may then be able to execute Gord's algorithm within the 2Gb limit.  Failing that, my SQL code was all built/tested on SQL 2005 Developer Edition and worked OK there, can't speak for SQL Express as I've not bothered with it (but you should know that it also has limits will at best cause poor performance, at worst will stop you in your tracks again).  I _strongly_ recommend you get SQL Standard Edition (at least), on trial, then buy it if it works for you.

Comment: @arcotenterprises I probably should clarify my earlier comment: If you are hitting the 2GB "wall" *for a single table* then you definitely have to migrate. If the database *in total* exceeds 2GB then you ***can*** work around the 2GB file size limit by splitting the very large tables off into separate .mdb/.accdb files and accessing them as linked tables, but that probably won't alleviate the speed issues (and by the sounds of it this project has scaled beyond what one might normally expect Access to handle anyway).

Comment: The single table "ExpectedResult" crosses 2GB limit , as there are no other big tables. The original source table has 80 - 100,000 rows from which these records are created. There is actually a scope where the data can be processed part by part , leveraging the use of VBA - hence was / am  very eager to share the file with you. No The project is not very complicated / big - juse some minor ironing out required. my email is username at g mail com

Comment: @GordThompson , I think I have figured out the solution , I will process the input table in parts. Generate Expected Result do my match and then delete and generate ExpectedRresult again for the second part and so on. But deleting the rows does not reduce the size. CompactAbdRepair cannot manually be done as I will be dividing hte input table into 20 - 25 parts. Not possible to do Compact and Repair manually every time.

Comment: @GordThompson , Which columns should be indexed for optimum performance. The number of Inserts will be very high. What I am considering is to let only few (essential for insert) columns indexed during the insert part to make it fast.
Then create an index using VBA - before proceeding to the next step of searching / matching the data.

Comment: @arcotenterprises I mentioned in my answer that the additional four (4) fields I added should be indexed (because they are used in JOINs and WHERE clauses). [ExpectedResult].[NumRows] should be indexed, too. You're right that other indexes will slow the INSERTs down so adding them after the process described above (and before you use the result set in queries joined to other tables) is a good idea

Comment: @GordThompson , So for the purpose of Insertion. We shall Index only SubjectBlock and NextSubjectBlockSeq. After the Insertion is complete I shall add Index on other columns. Please confirm if these are the only two columns which have to be indexed during insertion.

Comment: @GordThompson , One more thing - I am using an Access file "control.accdb" where I put the location of file to be worked upon instead of CurrentDB so that I can do the CompactRepair on that file after each Iteration. What should replacement for DCount(). cdb is the DAO Database. cdb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(strPath). For this the DCount has to be done , not the currently open file which has the Module code.

Comment: @GordThompson , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178626/improve-performance-access-vba-huge-number-of-inserts-index-caching-sq , Since this is fully your code - if you can just spend a few minutes and see the file once - I feel the work may get easily completed. Dropa blan email to arcotenterprises a.t. gmail com. I shall reply immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is:
"Please suggest how to speed this up. Better Algorithm / Code Improvements / Different Language to code Please assist."

I can answer *part* of your question quickly in short. "Different Language to code" == SQL.

In detail:

Whatever it is you're trying to achieve looks dataset intensive.  I'm almost certain this processing would be handled more efficiently within the DBMS that houses your data, as the DBMS is able to take a (reasonably well written) SQL query and optimise it based on its own knowledge of the data you are interrogating, and perform aggregation over large sets/sub-sets of data very quickly and efficiently.

Iterating over large datasets row-by-row to accumulate values is rarely (dare I say *never*) going to yield acceptable performance.  Which is why DBMSes don't do this natively (if you don't force them to by using iterative code, or code that needs to investigate each row, such as your VB code).

---

**Now, for the implementation** of Better Algorithm / Code Improvements / Different Language.

I've done this in SQL, but regardless of if you use my solution or not, I would still *highly* recommend you migrate your data to eg MS SQL or Oracle or mySql etc if you find that your use of MS Access is binding you to iterative approaches (which is not to suggest it *is* doing that... I don't know if this is the case or not).

But if this is genuinely not homework, and/or you are genuinely tied to MS Access, then perhaps an investment of effort to convert this to MS Access might be fruitful in terms of performance.  The principles should all be the same - it's a relational database and this is all fairly standard SQL, so I would've thought there'd be Access equivalents for what I've done here.

Failing that, you should be able to "point" an MSSQL instance at the MS Access file, as a linked server via an Access provider.  If you'd like advice on this, let me know.

There's some code here that is procedural by nature, in order to set up some "helper" tables that will allow the heavy-lifting aggregation on your sequences to be done using set-based operations.

I've called the source table "Your_Source_Table".  Do a search-replace on all instances to rename as whatever you've called it.

Note also that I haven't set up indexes on anything... you should do this.  Indexes should be created for all the columns involved in joins, I expect.  Checking the execution plan to ensure there's no unnecessary table scans would be wise.

I used the following to create Your_Source_Table:

```
-- Create Your apparent table structure
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Your_Source_Table]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Your_Source_Table]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Your_Source_Table](
    [DLID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Total] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And populated it as:

```
DLID        Subject    Total
----------- ---------- -----------
1           Science    70
2           Science    70
3           Science    70
4           Science    70
5           Maths      80
6           Maths      80
7           English    90
8           English    90
9           English    90
10          Science    75
```

Then, I created the following "helpers".  Explanations in code.

```
-- Set up helper structures.

-- Build a number table
if object_id('tempdb..##numbers') is not null
    BEGIN DROP TABLE ##numbers END
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number -- Can be 700, 800, or 900 contiguous rows, depending on which comment I read.  So I'll run with 100000 to be sure :-)
    INTO ##numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE ##numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)


-- Determine where each block starts.
if object_id('tempdb..#tempGroups') is not null
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #tempGroups END
GO
CREATE TABLE #tempGroups (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [StartID] [int] NULL,
    [Subject] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #tempGroups
    SELECT t.DLID, t.Subject FROM Your_Source_Table t WHERE DLID=1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        t.DLID, t.Subject
    FROM
        Your_Source_Table t
        INNER JOIN Your_Source_Table t2 ON t.DLID = t2.DLID+1 AND t.subject != t2.subject

-- Determine where each block ends
if object_id('tempdb..##groups') is not null
    BEGIN DROP TABLE ##groups END
CREATE TABLE ##groups (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StartID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EndID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO ##groups
SELECT
    g1.id as ID,
    g1.subject,
    g1.startID as startID,
    CASE
        WHEN g2.id is not null THEN g2.startID-1
        ELSE (SELECT max(dlid) FROM Your_Source_Table) -- Boundary case when there is no following group (ie return the last row)
    END as endID
FROM
    #tempGroups g1
    LEFT JOIN #tempGroups g2 ON g1.id = g2.id-1

DROP TABLE #tempGroups;
GO

-- We now have a helper table called ##groups, that identifies the subject, start DLID and end DLID of each continuous block of a particular subject in your dataset.
-- So now, we can build up the possible sequences within each group, by joining to a number table.
if object_id('tempdb..##sequences') is not null
    BEGIN DROP TABLE ##sequences END
CREATE TABLE ##sequences (
    [seqID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [groupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [start_of_sequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    [end_of_sequence] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO ##sequences
SELECT
    g.id,
    ns.number start_of_sequence,
    ne.number end_of_sequence
FROM
    ##groups g

    INNER JOIN ##numbers ns
    ON ns.number <= (g.endid - g.startid + 1) -- number is in range for this block

    INNER JOIN ##numbers ne
    ON ne.number <= (g.endid - g.startid + 1) -- number is in range for this block
    and ne.number >= ns.number -- end after start
ORDER BY
    1,2,3
```

Then, the results you're after can be achieved with a single set-based operation:

```
-- By joining groups to your dataset we can add a group identity to each record.
-- By joining sequences we can generate copies of the rows for aggregation into each sequence.
select 
    min(t.dlid) as ID, -- equals (s.start_of_sequence + g.startid - 1) (sequence positions offset by group start position)
    count(t.dlid) as number_of_rows,    
    g.subject,
    sum(t.total) as total

--select *
from
    Your_Source_Table t

    inner join ##groups g
    on t.dlid >= g.startid and t.dlid <= g.endid -- grouping rows into each group.

    inner join ##sequences s
    on s.groupid = g.id -- get the sequences for this group.
    and t.dlid >= (s.start_of_sequence + g.startid - 1) -- include the rows required for this sequence (sequence positions offset by group start position)
    and t.dlid <= (s.end_of_sequence + g.startid - 1)

group by
    g.subject,
    s.seqid

order by 2, 1
```

**BUT NOTE:** 
This result is NOT exactly the same as your "Expected Result". 
You've incorrectly included a duplicate instance of the 1 row sequence starting at row 1 (for science, sum total 1*70=70), but not included the 4 row sequence starting at row 1 (for science, sum total 4*70 = 280).

The correct results, IMHO are:

```
ID          number_of_rows subject    total
----------- -------------- ---------- -----------
1           1              Science    70 <-- You've got this row twice.
2           1              Science    70
3           1              Science    70
4           1              Science    70
5           1              Maths      80
6           1              Maths      80
7           1              English    90
8           1              English    90
9           1              English    90
10          1              Science    75
1           2              Science    140
2           2              Science    140
3           2              Science    140
5           2              Maths      160
7           2              English    180
8           2              English    180
1           3              Science    210
2           3              Science    210
7           3              English    270
1           4              Science    280 <-- You don't have this row.

(20 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks , was thinking about it right now.
Will have to work with "group by" try getting row count and sum.
But Is it possible to treat rows in a manner based on when they appear. I mean let used "group by" the first set of same subject eg. "science" , then a different row in the result would be for the second time "science" appears

You have the sample input table provided. Is it possible to have any query which may give the "Expected Result" as the result.

Comment: thanks for not going away to another question. 
Can you provide a query which can provide the result as shown in the sample from the input data table as shown in the sample.
Am not very good with Stored Procedures. Will be using the result for further matching using vbscript.

Comment: yes , The upper table is the source. What I am trying to achieve is the "Expected Result"

Comment: You're right, your answer does deserve a +1 on content alone. And, as non-Access answers to "Access questions" go, it's quite a bit closer than the vast majority. I'm still looking for the right balance when it comes to calling people to task for "answers" to Access questions that *do not work in Access*. The other difficulty is that many of the Access questions come from **complete** beginners, so handing them a T-SQL (or PL/SQL) solution and expecting them to "convert" it to work in Access is asking an awful lot.

Comment: @GordThompson Fair call. I honestly took "Other Languages" to mean eg T-SQL, for what it's worth.  And as I said in a recent edit, MS SQL can be pointed at the access DB to execute this stuff, which could be a compromise if the site is committed to Access.  Still interested in your opinion as to if you think this particular code _would_ convert to Access without too much pain? ...and thanks for the vote ;-)

Comment: @sepster , Thanks for the effort and advise about SQL. Have proceeded with Gord's technique , it works for Acccess system and is very intelligent. But would like to thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @arcotenterprises Absolutely my pleasure mate, good luck with it!

Comment: @Sepster , WIll require your help on this. Was able to implement the queries and code wit Gord's method , but my "ExpectedResult" crossess the access 2GB limit. And searching is also very slow for the post processing. Taking your advise - trying out in SQL server now.
Tried the queries mentioned above , works fine with the sample. But with my actual data which has around 90,000 rows - the query seems to be running forever. Are we missing something here - Index ?
Also Can I share the access file with you , so that you can have an idea of how I am connecting and trying to use the SQL.

Comment: Thanks so much sepster. , I ve copied the data from access and tried. I shall send you via email what I did in access and explain a bit. I really would be looking forward to hear from you.